# How to turnoff azure internally?

Tags: azure

We have a build machine which takes 3 to 4 hours to do the build process.
So, earlier it is in aws, so kept lambda to turnon during early morning and after 4 or 5 hours, the last step of build command is to send an email and turnoff the machine.

But, now we migrated to azure.
If we kept the same shutdown command here, the machine is getting shutdown but as per azure documentation, there is difference in shutdown command and turnoff using azure portal.As the billing will continue even the machine is shutdown.

How to setup this poweroff internally so that if any command ran inside the machine should reflect the turnoff in the azure portal.

Answer (score 1):

You can't deallocate (the term for turning off and no longer being charged) a machine from inside the VM, you need to talk to the Azure API to do this.
The simplest way would be to have your build process trigger an Azure Function or Azure Automation Job that runs some Azure PowerShell that runs the [Stop-AzVm command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/stop-azvm?view=azps-8.0.0) against that VM.